# Swift: Core Data - Resolving a logic issue with object creation

Tags: swift, core-data

So, my Swift app allows a user to choose sports teams to see historic match information for. Currently, a user selects team(s) and the JSON data file of historic matches is scanned.

If a historic match includes a name of a selected team, the details of the match are stored in a Core Data entity, which is fed into my main Table View.

However, this presents an issue I can't get my head around solving.

If a user selects team A and B, and the database contains a match where team A and B played EACH OTHER, two objects for the match details are created, and as such, Table View cell is created twice, once for team A being found in the instance of the match, and again for team B.

Is there an easy and efficient way to trim any duplicates caused in this way? I don't know whether to handle this at the object creation time, or just to find a way of removing any duplicated cells from my Table View.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should redesign your setup. Have all the records to be searched stored in Core Data.

If you have a hardcoded JSON file - import it on first start. If you have retrieved JSON - insert / update the elements that are new / changed in your Core Data object graph.

You would have a `Match` or `Game` entity and it would be retrieved only once. The fetch predicate would be something like

```
NSPredicate(format: "homeTeam = %@ || guestTeam = %@", selectedTeam, selectedTeam)
```

Comment: I thought that might be the case :S

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult. Any suggestions on how to limit the hardcoded JSON import to the first run of the app only?

Thanks again

Comment: Yes, just do a quick fetch and see if anything is there.

Comment: To include searching for the  Match items matching a date as a string, would something like this work:

NSPredicate(format: "matchDate == %@ && (homeTeam = %@ || awayTeam = %@)", dateAsString, selectedTeams)

Comment: That is a different question. You should accept this answer and ask a new question.